# Is box-sizing also a non-inheritable property just like margins and border properties are?

Tags: html, css, sass, frontend, box-sizing

I'm new to css and I tried playing with css inheritane. When I added `box-sizing:border-box` property to body , it doesn't get inherited by its child elements( in my case a `<section>` element). Is it just like other non inheritable properties like margins and borders ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, `box-sizing: border-box` is not inherited by child elements.

You can check the specification here https://drafts.csswg.org/css-ui-3/#box-sizing